# MSVC ignores throw statement

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, throw

At the current moment I am trying to test IAutoComplete COM interface, which requires me to make use of MSVC cpp compiler. I am faced with a problem I never faced in MingGW. MSVC sees my throw statement and completely ignores it. So I don't know if there is a setting I didn't set.

Alright I got a down vote which I probably deserve for giving a bad example. I thought that it failed to throw because it was in a struct but tries with a fresh struct proved me wrong. I might not be able to offer a reproducible example but I will try.

Prepare for alot of code.

Jav/AutoObject.h

```
#ifndef JAV_WIN32_AUTO_OBJECT_HPP
#define JAV_WIN32_AUTO_OBJECT_HPP

#include <Jav/config.h>

namespace Jav
{

struct AutoObject
{
 virtual ~AutoObject(){}
 void* operator new(size_t sz);
};

AutoObject* shallowCopy(AutoObject*);
AutoObject* deleteObject(AutoObject*);

}

#endif // JAV_WIN32_AUTO_OBJECT_HPP
```

Jav/win32/widgets/widgets_ex.h

```
#ifndef JAV_WIN32_GUI_WIDGETS_EX_HPP
#define JAV_WIN32_GUI_WIDGETS_EX_HPP

#include <Jav/win32/widgets/widgets.h>


namespace Jav {  namespace win32 {

class Widget
{
 public:
    Widget(HWND widget=nullptr) : widget(widget){}
    operator HWND() { return widget; }

 public:
    void setId(int id) { SetWindowLong(widget,GWLP_ID,id); }
    void destroy()   { DestroyWindow(widget); widget = NULL; }
    void show()     { ShowWindow(widget,SW_SHOW); }
    void hide()     { ShowWindow(widget,SW_HIDE); }

 protected:
     HWND widget;
};

}}

#endif // JAV_WIN32_GUI_WIDGETS_EX_HPP
```

Jav/win32/window/Window.h

```
#include <Jav/win32/widgets/widgets_ex.h>
using Window = Widget;
```

Jav/win32/window/SimpleWindow.h

```
#ifndef JAV_WIN32_WINDOW_SIMPLE_WINDOW_HPP
#define JAV_WIN32_WINDOW_SIMPLE_WINDOW_HPP

#include <Jav/AutoObject.h>
#include <Jav/win32/window/Window.h>



namespace Jav  { namespace win32 {

struct Content__ : AutoObject
{
 virtual void onCreate(HWND,CREATESTRUCTA*) {}
 virtual void onDestroy() {}
 virtual void onSize(int w,int h) {}
 virtual void onDraw(Canvas&) {}
};

class SimpleWindow : public Window
{
 public:
    SimpleWindow(Content__*, const char *title, size_t w,size_t h,
                   int style=WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
                   int ex_style=0);

 public:
    bool isOpen();
    void close();
    const MSG& getMessage();
    const MSG& peekMessage();
    void dispatchMessage(const MSG&);

 private:
    static ATOM registerWindow();
    static LRESULT CALLBACK windowProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
    static HWND createWindow(Content__*, const char *,HMENU, size_t,size_t, int,int);

 private:
    MSG msg;
};

}}

#endif // JAV_WIN32_WINDOW_SIMPLE_WINDOW_HPP
```

AutoObject.cpp

```
#include <Jav/AutoObject.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <objbase.h>


namespace {

struct AutoObjectsMap : std::unordered_map<Jav::AutoObject*,size_t>
{
 ~AutoObjectsMap() { for(auto &obj : *this) CoTaskMemFree(obj.first); }
};

AutoObjectsMap *alloc_objects_ptr;

struct AutoObjectsMapMgr
{
 ~AutoObjectsMapMgr() { delete alloc_objects_ptr; };
};

}

#define alloc_objects (*alloc_objects_ptr)

namespace Jav
{

void* AutoObject::operator new(size_t sz)
{
 auto mem = CoTaskMemAlloc(sz);
 if(!alloc_objects_ptr) alloc_objects_ptr = new AutoObjectsMap();
 alloc_objects[(AutoObject*)mem] = 1;
 return mem;
}

AutoObject* shallowCopy(AutoObject *r)
{
 auto elem = alloc_objects.find(r);
 if( elem != alloc_objects.end() ) ++alloc_objects[r];
 return r;
}

AutoObject* deleteObject(AutoObject *mem)
{
    auto elem = alloc_objects.find(mem);

    if( elem != alloc_objects.end() )
    {
        if(--elem->second == 0)
        {
         mem->~AutoObject();
         CoTaskMemFree(mem);
         alloc_objects.erase(elem);
         return nullptr;
        }
    }

    return mem;
}

}
```

SimpleWindow.cpp

```
#include <Jav/win32/window/SimpleWindow.h>


namespace Jav  { namespace win32 {

namespace {

LRESULT CALLBACK SimpleWindow::windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Content__ *obj = (Content__*)GetWindowLongPtrA(hwnd,GWLP_USERDATA);

    auto getWidth  = [lParam](){ return LOWORD(lParam); };
    auto getHeight = [lParam](){ return HIWORD(lParam); };
    auto getX = [lParam](){ return LOWORD(lParam); };
    auto getY = [lParam](){ return HIWORD(lParam); };
    auto getWidget     = [lParam](){ return (HWND)lParam; };
    auto widgetId      = [wParam](){ return LOWORD(wParam); };
    auto widgetEvent   = [wParam](){ return HIWORD(wParam); };
    auto menuType      = [wParam](){ return LOWORD(wParam); };
    auto eventId       = [wParam](){ return LOWORD(wParam); };

    switch (uMsg)
    {
     case WM_CREATE:
        {
         CREATESTRUCT *cs = ((CREATESTRUCTA*)lParam);
         obj = (Content__*)cs->lpCreateParams;
         SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWLP_USERDATA,(LONG_PTR)obj);
         obj->onCreate(hwnd,cs);
         return 0;
        }

     case WM_DESTROY:
        obj->onDestroy();
        deleteObject(obj);
        return 0;

     case WM_SIZE:
        obj->onSize(getWidth(),getHeight());
        return 0;

     default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

ATOM SimpleWindow::registerWindow()
{
 WNDCLASSEX wincl = {};

 wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
 wincl.lpszClassName = "JavWin32WindowSimpleWindow";
 wincl.lpfnWndProc = SimpleWindow::windowProc;
 wincl.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
 wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);;
 wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
 wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
 wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
 wincl.cbWndExtra = WINDOW_WND_EXTRA_BYTES;

 return RegisterClassEx(&wincl);
}

SimpleWindow::SimpleWindow(Content__ *obj,const char *title, size_t w,size_t h, int style,int ex_style)
 : Window( createWindow(obj,title,NULL, w,h, style,ex_style) ),
   app_ctx(*this)
{
 msg.message = 0;
 show();
}

bool SimpleWindow::isOpen()
{
 return msg.message != WM_QUIT;
}

void SimpleWindow::close()
{
 DestroyWindow(*this);
}

const MSG& SimpleWindow::getMessage()
{
 GetMessageA(&msg,*this,0,0);
 return msg;
}

const MSG& SimpleWindow::peekMessage()
{
 PeekMessageA(&msg,*this,0,0,PM_REMOVE);
 return msg;
}

void SimpleWindow::dispatchMessage(const MSG &msg)
{
 TranslateMessage(&msg);
 DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

}}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Jav/AutoObject.h>
#include <Jav/win32/window/SimpleWindow.h>


using namespace Jav::win32;

class Content : public Content__
{
    IAutoComplete *pac = NULL;
    IAutoComplete2 *pac2 = NULL;
    //IUnknown *punkSource;
    //ColumnList columnList;

 public:
    ~Content()
    {
        if(pac) pac->Release();
        if(pac2) pac2->Release();
    }

    void onCreate(HWND hwnd,CREATESTRUCTA*)override
    {
        throw; //doesn't throw or terminate
        HWND textBox; // pretend this is an edit control
        attachAutoCompleteObject(textBox); //doesn't throw either
    }

    void attachAutoCompleteObject(HWND hwnd)
    { 
        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AutoComplete, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pac));
        if(FAILED(hr)) throw "Failed to create AutoComplete Object\n";
    
        hr = pac->Init(hwnd, &columnList, NULL, NULL);
        if(FAILED(hr)) throw "Failed to attach auto complete object\n";
    
        hr = pac->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pac2)); rep(pac2);
        if (FAILED(hr)) throw "Failed to set autocomplete options\n";

        hr = pac2->SetOptions(ACO_AUTOSUGGEST);
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    Content content;
    SimpleWindow win(&content,"",640,480);

    while(win.isOpen())
    {
     auto &msg = win.getMessage();
     win.dispatchMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't even compile

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You are supposed to throw an object...

Comment: My point is to just terminate the program. But the program continues as if no throw was encountered. And I did try the throw object version.

Answer (score 1):

So you appear to have `throw "literal"` instead of just `throw;` you originally posted. Then it indeed should throw. The problem here is that you attempt to throw exception that goes through Windows DLLs, like `GetMessage`/`DispatchMessage` fuctions or COM method dispatch, which is not guarrantied to work.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. I was thinking along these lines as I had experience where throwing from extern C didn't work, but I couldn't find anything concrete. I still don't exactly understand this is a problem as my function is from a Cpp context and is not a callback to a win32 function, but atleast what you said sounds valid.

Comment: Looking back, my code is ran in the window procedure callback. MinGw is able to throw exceptions in the Window Procedure callback, but MSVC doesn't. Your answer is spot on.

Comment: @user13947194, MSVC uses SEH  -- structured exception handling. MinGW uses SJLJ SetJump LongJump, or Dwarf-2 https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WindowsGCCImprovements . These mechanism are not visible to MSVC-compiled code. There's no way to make MSVC use other mechanism than SEH.